# How to obfuscate a library jar in ProGuard?

Tags: java, obfuscation, proguard

I have a jar that uses another jar as a library. I want them both to be obfuscated.
Quoting ProGuard [documentation](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/#manual/introduction.html):

> ProGuard requires the library jars (or wars, ears, zips, or
>   directories) of the input jars to be specified. These are essentially
>   the libraries that you would need for compiling the code. ProGuard
>   uses them to reconstruct the class dependencies that are necessary for
>   proper processing. **The library jars themselves always remain
>   unchanged**. You should still put them in the class path of your final
>   application.

How can I change this behavior?

**UPDATE:**
I cannot use incremental obfuscation because I wouldn't know what to specify as entry points for the library jar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to specify your two jars as input jars (with the option `-injars`). They will then both be obfuscated. Any other jars, such as the run-time jar, are library jars (specified with the option `-libraryjars`). ProGuard needs them to properly process your code, but it leaves them unchanged.

Comment: "... it leaves them unchanged" did you mean any JAR will not be obfuscated, even ones specified in `-injars`?